# Struts2 Exception handling usage?

Tags: java, jsp, exception, struts2

I have my `Action` class below in which `getTspNameIdMap` throws `ReqMgmtException` exception (custom exception).

```
public String findTspNameIdMap(){

        SlsReqMgmtCommonRemote slsReqMgmtCommonRemote = null;
        tspNameIdMap = new HashMap<String, String>();

        try{
            slsReqMgmtCommonRemote = getSlsReqMgmtCommonRemote();
            tspNameIdMap = slsReqMgmtCommonRemote.getTspNameIdMap(gmaThresholdParameters.getId().getCircleId());

        }
        catch(ReqMgmtException rEx){
            addActionError(rEx.getError());
            result = "error";
            return ERROR;
        }
        catch (Exception e){    
            addActionError("Error in processing your request. Contact Administrator");
            e.printStackTrace();
            System.out.println("[ConfigureTspThresholdAction: findTspNameIdMap Function]:In catch Inside Constructor!!");
            result = "error";
            return ERROR;
        }
        return SUCCESS;
    }
```

I know there is exception handling in Struts2 too, however presently I am not using it. 
Should I use Struts2 exception handling? What would be its usage?

Comment: Whether or not you "should" use S2's declarative exception handling depends *entirely* on your needs. It's used to process exceptions you don't want to handle directly inside application code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use exception handling mechanism in Struts2, that's what `exception` interceptor provides. Also you should handle exceptions in the action method like in your question. If it handles all exceptions good, if not the exception handler could handle it. Also in some methods which doesn't have `throws Exception` signature you can only catch the exception but cannot return `ERROR` result. So, rethrowing the exception and handling it by the interceptor is the workaround.

**References:**

- [Exception handling in struts2 and hibernate](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14859757/573032)
- [Which Exceptions to declare/handle in struts xml](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20727459/573032)
- [Struts 2 what to do when user inserts action which does not exist](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20452850/573032)
- [how to validate json being sent using struts2 json plugin without throwing exception](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20953704/573032)