# How to handle exceptions thrown by default interceptors in struts2?

Tags: java, exception, struts2, interceptor

For example:

```
org.apache.commons.fileupload.FileUploadBase$SizeLimitExceededException: 
the request was rejected because its size (337867) exceeds the configured 
maximum (200)
```

Comment: [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21136394/573032) might help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use exception mapping feature of Struts2 to map exception to specific `result`.

In `struts.xlm` file put `<exception-mapping>` definition inside `<global-exception-mappings>` and create `result`, with defined name, global or in specific action(s).

```
<global-exception-mappings>
  <exception-mapping exception="java.lang.NullPointerException" result="npe"/>
</global-exception-mappings>
```

Note that your interceptor stack must include `exception` interceptor. Also it is recommended that `exception` interceptor would be the first interceptor on the stack, ensuring that it has full access to catch any exception, even those caused by other interceptors.

Comment: I am not getting, can u give some more information.Thank u.

Comment: @user2709752: What exactly you are *not getting*? S2 `exception` interceptor will map exception to defined result.

Comment: I don't have any custom interceptors ,so where should I include exception interceptor.